# using libgdx 1.1, how to import a project on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I am quite a beginner in java and trying to get started on making android applications. As far as I understand adding external libraries using libgdx is quite helpful. There, I downloaded lastest version and created a project. Now I am basically following this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBsvuT7MzpY

However, I cannot import the project I created using 'gradle', because I am not provided the gradle option to choose when I click import (29th second on the video).

So I am basically wondering what I should do to see the gradle option when I do file>import on any eclipse project. Thank you.

I am sure that this question is quite easy and kind of stupid but I would really appreciate any help. I didn't take any course so I am trying to learn java using youtube videos etc. Honestly I didn't even understand the difference between libgdx or gradle.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I recognized that I overlooked the following webpage.

[https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-(Eclipse,-Intellij-IDEA,-NetBeans)](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Setting-up-your-Development-Environment-%28Eclipse,-Intellij-IDEA,-NetBeans%29)

hope it helps other beginners too.